# Determine the limiting distribution for $\overline{X}^{2}$, where $\overline{X}$ is the sample mean

Tags: distributions, mean, convergence, central-limit-theorem, asymptotics

This question is related somewhat to one that somebody else asked [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125309/what-is-the-limiting-distribution-of-the-sample-mean). Aside from the fact that I don't feel as if that question was sufficiently answered, my question is not about the exact same thing.

I am being asked to determine the limiting distribution for the square of the sample mean, $\overline{X}^{2}$, where $\overline{X}$ is the sample mean from a population with finite mean and variance.

However, I, unlike the other OP, have absolutely no idea how to approach this. I am also not sure how they were supposed to get it converging to something normal-like without knowing about how $X$ is distributed in the first place. In my notes, this problem is given alongside a theorem characterizing weak convergence of measures, but I don't see how to apply that here.

Comment: Have you heard of the Central Limit Theorem? Presumably you have because you included that as a tag, but I am surprised you don't mention it at all in your question. If $\bar X$ is asymptotically normal, as the CLT gives, then $\bar X^2$ will be scaled non-central chisquare on 1 df. (You must be familiar with non-central chisquare because you asked about it in a previous question.)

Comment: @GordonSmyth how do I know that $\overline{X}$ is asymptotically normal, though? Or is that something that the CLT tells us?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what the CLT tells you.

Comment: @GordonSmyth okay, on the page in the typed up lecture notes our prof gives us, the top of the page is entitled "Central Limit Theorem", but I'm not sure that the theorem given on that page is actually it. It says "Suppose $X_{1},X_{2}, \cdots $ are i.i.d. r.v's with finite $E[X_{i}] = \mu$ and $Var[X_{i}]=\sigma^{2}$. Then, $\frac{\sqrt{n}(\overline{X}-\mu)}{\sigma} = \frac{\overline{X}-\mu}{\sqrt{\sigma^{2}/n}}= \frac{S_{n}-n\mu}{\sqrt{n \sigma^{2}}} \to^{L} Z \sim N(0,1)$ as $n \to \infty$." Is this it? Because it's called Lindberg-Levy here.

Comment: @GordonSmyth anyway, I don't think we want it to be STANDARD normal asymptotically, because that's what this theorem gives us. This is the only theorem listed on this page, and nowhere else in the chapter is there anything else remotely CLT-like listed. So, you can see why I'm so confused.

Comment: Under reasonable assumptions (like finite variance and mean), the CLT does work...and exactly what those assumptions are, and how weak they can be, are what give rise to 'alternate' CLT definitions.  But they all give the same result.  Wikipedia actually does an OK job on this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem

Comment: @Jeff Take care. Asymptotically, $\bar{X}$ goes to a constant (as will its square, each under suitable conditions); it's a standardized version of $\bar{X}$ (e.g. $sqrt{n}(\bar{X}-\mu)$) for which the CLT applies.

Comment: It is a direct application of delta method. For a more transparent solution, see @Simth's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the [Delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method) here. From your lecture notes,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_n-\mu)}{\sigma}&\overset{d}{\to}N(0,1),\text{ or}\\
\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_n-\mu)&\overset{d}{\to}N(0,\sigma^2).
\end{align*}
The idea here is to expand $g(\bar{X}_n)=\bar{X}_n^2$ about $\mu$:
\begin{align*}
\bar{X}_n^2=\mu^2+2\mu(\bar{X}_n-\mu)+(\bar{X}_n-\mu)^2.
\end{align*}
Then 
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_n^2-\mu^2)=2\mu\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_n-\mu)+\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_n-\mu)^2.
\end{align*}
If you can show $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_n-\mu)^2\overset{P}{\to}0$, then [Slutsky's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slutsky%27s_theorem) implies that both sides tend to $N(0, 4\mu^2\sigma^2)$.

Edit: Just in case it was unclear, you must show that the second term of the right hand side in the final equation converges to 0. Then you use the central limit theorem to get that the first term of the right hand side, and therefore the left hand side, goes to $N(0, 4\mu^2\sigma^2)$.

Comment: $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X} - \mu)^2$ does converge to $0$ in probability, if you would like to write it as $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X} - \mu) \times (\bar{X} - \mu)$.

Comment: @GordonSmyth The problem is that the non-centrality parameter diverges: $\bar{X}_n^2=n^{-1}\|P_1X\|^2\to \sigma^2 n^{-1}\chi^2_{1;\|P_1\mu\|/\sigma} =\sigma^2n^{-1}\chi^2_{1;n\mu/\sigma}$

Comment: @GordonSmyth  I ran some simulations and I believe $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}-\mu)^2$ converges to 0. And the "limiting distribution" for a sequence $T_n$, as I've seen it defined in courses, is any distribution $F$ such that there exist sequences of real numbers $b_n, 0\neq a_n$ such that $a_n(T_n-b_n)\overset{d}{\to}F$.

Comment: @GordonSmyth You must have confused $\sqrt{n}$ with $n$. Did you seriously consider my decomposition, where $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X} - \mu) \to_d N(0, \sigma^2)$ and $\bar{X} - \mu \to_d 0$?

Comment: Even though we assume the normalizing constant is $n$, unless the underlying distribution is normal, how can you say "it is distributed as $\sigma^2\chi_1^2$ regardless of $n$"?

Comment: @Zhanxiong so is Smith's solution correct or not?

Comment: @Jeff It is correct and a well-written proof. But it actually didn't apply the delta method, if so, the proof is one line. That may be the only confusing part as he mentioned delta method.

Comment: @Smith I understand what you're saying, but what I'm not sure about still is how to show that $\sqrt{n}(\overline{X}-\mu)^{2}$ converges to $0$ in probabillity. Zhanxiong is saying to write it as $\sqrt{n}(\overline{X}-\mu) \cdot (\overline{X}-\mu)$. Then, you have that $\sqrt{n}(\overline{X}-\mu)$ converges to $N(0, \sigma^{2})$ in distribution, and I'm assuming $\overline{X}$ converges to $\mu$ because of the central limit theorem, so that $\overline{X} - \mu$ converges to $0$, but then how does this give us that the whole thing converges in probability to $0$?

Comment: @Smith or, I can show by the WLLN and the continuous mapping theorem for convergence in probability that $(\overline{X}_{n}-\mu)^{2}  \to^{P} 0$, but then what do I do with the $\sqrt{n}$ part? This is really the only part of this I am still having problems with.

Comment: @Zhanxiong, if you're around, you could answer these concerns as well.

Comment: @Jeff The claim follows a simple property which states that $O_P(1) \cdot o_P(1) = o_P(1)$. If you have concerns regarding this property, ask a new question and I may give you a proof.

Comment: @Zhanxiong so it's a little-O, big-O thing? Is that what you're saying?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70580/discussion-between-zhanxiong-and-jeff).